# How to build a dictionary of words in text

Tags: python, dictionary

How would I return a dictionary with the key being a word in the given text and the values being a list of previous words in the text?

e.g.

```
text = "hi my name is"    
get_previous_words_dict(text):
```

prints a dictionary:

```
>>> my_dict['hi']
[]
>>> my_dict['my']
['hi']    
>>> my_dict['name']
['hi', 'my']
```

Comment: What happens if you have the same word again? In the sentence **"you are what you are"** for example, what is get_previous_words("you")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only makes sense if the words in the sentence are unique, as @cjds points out. Also, the value for the first word should surely be an empty list, not a list containing the empty string. The following will fit this specification:

```
def get_previous_words_dict(text):
    words = []
    dictionary = {}
    for word in text.split():
        dictionary[word] = words[:]
        words.append(word)
    return dictionary
```

The most important thing to understand is the assignment:

```
dictionary[word] = words[:]
```

The effect of this is to copy the words array. If it was a normal assignment:

```
dictionary[word] = words
```

Then that would just make each dictionary entry refer to the same `words` list, and so at the end of the loop every entry in the dictionary would have all of the words.

Comment: It would be good if you could clarify what you are doing with `word[:]`.

Comment: would list(words) be easier to understand?

Comment: I think it depends what you're used to. For me `words[:]` has always been the canonical way of copying a list.

Comment: Hi, thanks I got the answer but my actual text has repeated words, how would I make it so it returns non repeated words?

Comment: @J_lll: A dictionary only accepts unique keys, so if your text is "I am what I am" then it is impossible to make two key 'I'.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> t="hi my name is"
>>> li=t.split()
```

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {w:[li[si] for si in range(i-1,-1,-1)] for i, w in enumerate(li)}
{'is': ['name', 'my', 'hi'], 'hi': [], 'my': ['hi'], 'name': ['my', 'hi']}
```

Or, counting up:

```
>>> {w:[li[si] for si in range(0,i)] for i, w in enumerate(li)}
{'is': ['hi', 'my', 'name'], 'hi': [], 'my': ['hi'], 'name': ['hi', 'my']}
```

Or use a slice instead of the nested list comprehension:

```
>>> {w:li[0:i] for i, w in enumerate(li)}
{'is': ['hi', 'my', 'name'], 'hi': [], 'my': ['hi'], 'name': ['hi', 'my']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were to implement from scratch:

Use a hash to store words, this used as dictionary. 
When insert into hash, insert as key => [previous keys in hash].

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the sentence into words:

   ```
   sentence_words = sentence.split(' ')
   ```
2. Create a dictionary where the key is the word, and the value is a slice of `sentence_words` from the beginning to the position of this word.

   ```
   d = {w: sentence_words[:i] for i, w in enumerate(sentence_words)}
   ```

#### Sample Code

```
sentence = "Hi my name is John"
sentence_words = sentence.split(' ')
d = {w: sentence_words[:i] for i, w in enumerate(sentence_words)}
```